# How to add a text on each line of multiple txt files

Tags: php

I have a folder with multiple .txt files, i need to add to each line of each txt a string.

This is what i have so far

```
<?php

    $path = realpath('C:\xampp\htdocs\name reservation');   
    $line = '';

    $fileList = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach ($fileList as $file) {

        if ($file->isFile() && stripos($file->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) {

            $file_contents = file_get_contents($file->getPathName());
            file_put_contents($file->getPathName(), "--->>>" . "\n" . $file_contents) . PHP_EOL;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: On that example i'm tring to add the "--->>>" as the string on each line of my multiple txt files, but the code just add it on the first line.

Comment: Because you're not looping the lines in the file.  Try using `file` and imploding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're not looping the lines in the file. Try using `file` to get an array of lines and imploding.

```
foreach ($fileList as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile() && stripos($file->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) {
        $file_contents = file($file->getPathName());
        $file_contents = "--->>>" . implode("--->>>", $file_contents);
        file_put_contents($file->getPathName(), $file_contents);
    }
}
```

You have a stray `PHP_EOL` and you may need to add a `\n` somewhere as I can't tell where exactly you want the `--->>>`.

Comment: Wow, almost done dude! thanks for your answer, now i just have a little problem to fix.

--->>>dato1
--->>>dato2
--->>>

Thats what i got, now the "--->>>" was added correctly but i have an extra one at the end of each txt.

Comment: You have to be more specific about how you want it to look and what you get.  Edit into question so you can format it correctly.

Comment: Sorry about that, i did it.

I post your solution with the "\n" that i needed. Thanks friend.

foreach ($fileList as $file) {

  if ($file->isFile() && stripos($file->getPathName(), 'txt') !== false) {

      $file_contents = file($file->getPathName());
      $file_contents = "REEMPLAZAR" . implode("REEMPLAZAR", $file_contents)."\n";
         file_put_contents($file->getPathName(), $file_contents);
 
  }

 }